# Define $h(x) = x^3\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x\neq0$ and $h(0) = 0$. Show that $h$ is differentiable and that $h'$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Define $h(x) = x^3\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x \neq0$ and $h(0) = 0$. Show that $h$ is differentiable everywhere and that $h'$ is continuous everywhere, but fails to have a derivative at a point.

This problem is posed from a real analysis perspective, looking back on calculus concepts; it is meant to be a proof. It doesn't appear to warrant a delta epsilon strategy, however.

Comment: Be sure to use \dfrac instead of \over when typing $\LaTeX$.  This makes the equation easily readable.

Comment: @NasuSama how does the syntax there work? would it be $ 1 \dfrac x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the difference quotient at $0$:

$$\frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x} = x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$$

By the squeeze theorem, this tends to $0$ as $x \to 0$, since $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$.

The function is clearly differentiable away from $0$, and its derivative is given by

$$h'(x) = 3x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x} + x^3 \cos{\frac{1}{x}} \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 3x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}} - x \cos\frac{1}{x}$$

This tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$ for the same reason, so $h'$ is continuous.